# Grid-lines are being recreated and overlaid on each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm playing with some d3 code - to create the y axis I do the following :

```
function renderYAxis(svg) { 

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .orient("left")
     .scale(_y.range([quadrantHeight(), 0]))
     .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

 axisData = _currentData.filter(function(row) {
     if ((row['filter1'] === _filter1)) {
         return true;
     }
 }).filter(function(row) {
     if ((row['filter2'] === _filter2)) {
         return true;
     }
 }).map(function(d) {
     return {
         y: +d["Y"]
     };
 });
 var minY2 = d3.min(axisData, function(d) { return d.y });
 if (minY2 > 0) {
     minY2 = 0;
 };
 _y.domain([minY2, d3.max(axisData, function(d) { return d.y })])


 if (!_axesYG) {
     _axesYG = svg
         .append("g")
         .attr("class", "y axis"); 
 }

 _axesYG
     .attr("transform", function() {
         return "translate(" + xStart() + "," + yEnd() + ")";
     })
     .transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .call(yAxis);

  //>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> maybe following needs changing somehow? >>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  d3.selectAll("g.y g.tick")
     .append("line")
     .classed("grid-line", true)
     .attr("x1", 0)
     .attr("y1", 0)
     .attr("x2", quadrantWidth())
     .attr("y2", 0);

}
```

The chart has a transition but after transitioning several times some of the grid lines are reproducing and being laid on top of each other - so producing some thicker lines. I've marked above where I think the problem may be, I'm unsure how to change this code - is there a standard approach?

A full working example of the behavior is saved here: http://plnkr.co/edit/JD52TfAddZSpNR3oaMRv?p=preview

If you hit the button several times you will see it is the *common* grid lines that are shared before and after the transition that are being recreated and overlaid. These two:

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: looks like you are not using the **general update pattern** correctly, you can read this example to understand the flow better: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple fix (hack), since the original code structure is hard to change to follow General Update Pattern correctly:

```
      // remove old ones
      d3.selectAll(".grid-line.y-axis")
         .remove();

      // draw new ones
      // add a new class y-axis to avoid deleting the x axis above
      d3.selectAll("g.y g.tick")
         .append("line")
         .classed("grid-line y-axis", true)
         .attr("x1", 0)
         .attr("y1", 0)
         .attr("x2", quadrantWidth())
         .attr("y2", 0);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/wdQmllRrrILtXsarXqLY?p=preview

The more correct approach is to follow the General Update Pattern: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Comment: i think this is fine - the general update pattern is a bit tricky to apply to the grid-lines

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution is just setting the tick width with a negative value:

```
.innerTickSize(-quadrantWidth());
```

That way, you don't have to worry about appending, removing or updating the lines, and you won't have duplicated elements: the axis generator takes care of all that for you.

Here is the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/BoP4hEkILlwJzRuCJFBD?p=preview

EDIT: you mentioned in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46521285/5768908) that you're having problems with Nick Zhu's approach. That's because your selection is not correct. It should be something like this:

```
var lines = d3.selectAll("g.y g.tick")

lines.selectAll(".grid-line")
    .remove();

lines.append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", quadrantWidth())
    .attr("y2", 0);
```

Here is the respective plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/189hJBepdVVreLghBgc0?p=preview

Comment: true to form - a very nice approach!

Comment: it works great but you've got rid of the code which sets the grid-line x1, x2 etc. ... and it still works perfect... what is happening here? How does the chart know what grid-lines to use? (Geraldo: any additional reading I can do to get my head around what is happening)

Comment: Yes, the axis generator is dealing with that. By the way, check my edit (about your answer).

Answer (score 1):

just for completeness I thought I'd add the following, which I found in Nick Qi Zhu's book. I think it follows the general update pattern as well as grid-lines can. Although even adding this I still get a reproduction of the grid-lines!

```
function renderYGridlines() {
     var lines = d3.selectAll("g.y g.tick")
       .select("grid-line y-axis")
       .remove();

     lines = d3.selectAll("g.y g.tick")
       .append("line")
       .classed("grid-line", true)

     lines.attr("x1", 0)
       .attr("y1", 0)
       .attr("x2", quadrantWidth())
       .attr("y2", 0);
   }
```